# Bulk operations using spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Is it possible to perform MongoDB bulk operations (like update/upsert) using ReactiveMongoTemplate or spring-data-mongodb-reactive?